# How to pick multiple properties from an array using underscorejs?

Tags: underscore.js

How to pick multiple properties from an array using only **underscorejs** ?

var arr = [{Analytics:16}, {Technology:12}, {Medical:20}, {Operations:40}]

Output i required in the below format.
[12,40,20,16]

Thanks

Comment: How to get only specific value from an array. Example, i need only "Medical" value i.e, [20]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr = [{Analytics:16}, {Technology:12}, {Medical:20}, {Operations:40}];
var output = [];

_.each(arr, function (e){output.push(_.flatten(e)[0])});

output = [16, 12, 20, 40];
```

Comment: How to get only specific value from an array. Example, i need only "Medical" value i.e, [20]

Comment: `_.reject(_.pluck(arr, "Medical"), function(val){ return _.isUndefined(val) }) ` for getting medical

Answer (score 1):

You could first [**map**](http://underscorejs.org/#map) over the array and get the [**values**](http://underscorejs.org/#values) and then [**flatten**](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) the result:

```
var result = _.flatten(_.map(arr, _.values));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [{Analytics:16}, {Technology:12}, {Medical:20}, {Operations:40}];
_.map(arr,function(m){return _.values(m)[0]});
```